# How do you combine wavelengths of particles in an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms, wavelength

As the problem below results in the wavelength of a single electron, how would this combine/interact with other particles? In an atom, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently exactly the same, as shown in references cited in [Physicists Smash Record For Wave-Particle Duality](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b).